# parse a unix timestamp to date in emacs (elisp)

Tags: datetime, emacs

Given `1525505457`, return a date object(`Sat May 05 2018 15:30:57 GMT+0800 (CST)`) representing it.

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_parse_time.html this article only tell how to format a date to unix time, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the combination of `decode-time` & `seconds-to-time`, like this:

```
(decode-time (seconds-to-time 1525505457))
=> (57 30 9 5 5 2018 6 t 7200)
```

The same module, `time-date.el` has other functions for conversion into time object, like string, etc.:

```
(decode-time (date-to-time "2018-05-05T12:33:05Z"))
=> (5 33 14 5 5 2018 6 t 7200)
```